# Prove that $f(x,y)=\max\{x ,y\}$ is continuous

Tags: analysis, continuity

Hi i need to prove that $f(x, y) = \max\{x,y\}$ is continuous.

$\max\{x,y\} = \dfrac{x + y + |x - y|}{2}$,
and thats continuous because + and \ are continuous?

Comment: What is the backslash?

Comment: Divide for example a/b

Comment: Not only then. You need to know the absolute value is a continuous function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $(x,y) \in \Bbb{R}^2$ and  $(x_n,y_n) \to (x,y)$ in $\Bbb{R^2}$

In other words $$||(x_n,y_n)-(x,y)||_2=\sqrt{(x_n-x)^2+(y_n-y)^2} \to 0$$

Then $x_n \to x$ and $y_n \to y$.

You have to  prove that $\max\{x_n,y_n\} \to \max\{x,y\}$

We have that  $$x_n+y_n \to x+y$$ $$|x_n-y_n| \to |x-y|$$

Thus $$f(x_n,y_n)=\frac{x_n+y_n+|x_n-y_n|}{2} \to \frac{x+y+|x-y|}{2}=f(x,y)$$

proving the $f$ is continuous at $(x,y)$.

Answer (score 2):

> $\max\{x,y\} = \dfrac{x + y + |x - y|}{2}$, and thats continuous because + and \ are continuous?

This idea is fine, assuming you know (and are allowed to use the fact) that the absolute value is a continuous function and that the sum (and scalar multiples) of continuous functions remain continuous.

Answer (score 0):

What you said is fine, if you already know that the absolute value function is continuous, and if you mention that.

You might instead say:

- When $x\ge y$ then, directly from the definition, $\max(x,y) =x$ which is trivially continuous.
- When $x<y$ then $\max(x,y) =y$ which is also continuous.

So the function is continuous everywhere.